# R leaflet easybutton : reset view to layer bbox

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm having some troubles with the easybutton leaflet plugin in my Shiny App.
What I'm trying to do is to recenter the view on my points layer when the easybutton is clicked :

```
    ...
    addCircleMarkers(lng = points$long,
                     lat = points$lat,
                     weight = 1, radius = 4,
                     group = "points", 
                     ...

    addEasyButton(easyButton(
      icon = 'ion-arrow-shrink',
      title = 'Reset view',
      onClick = JS("function(btn, map) {map.fitBounds(points.getBounds()); }") 
    ))
```

But it doesn't work : "points is not defined" is printed in the JS console.

How can I get the real leaflet name (JS) of my points layer ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite being a group name, `points` is not defined within the javascript - you need to use the layerManager to find layers - and passing the layer name from R to js is not quite as straightforward as one might hope.

This is not very clear in the documentation, but you should be able to set a group name for the markers, as you have, and then access it like so:

```
onClick = JS("function(btn, map) { 
   var groupLayer = map.layerManager.getLayerGroup('groupName');
}")
```

To get the bounds you should be able to use:

```
   onClick = JS("function(btn, map) { 
       var groupLayer = map.layerManager.getLayerGroup('groupName');
       map.fitBounds(groupLayer.getBounds());
    }")
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed.